# Crashing at Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

Facing issue with the

> (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

.Tried a lot but i am not able to solve it. Following is my code what i have tried. Getting issue at `NSDictionary *thisRow = [self. EmployeeArr objectAtIndex:row];`
        (Getting issue here, the issue is "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS"). Please help me to find the issue. TIA

```
EmployeesVC.h

@interface Employees : UITableViewController<CacheDBDelegate,JsonServiceClsDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate> {
    CacheDBCommands *cacheDB;
    MBProgressHUD *countryHUD;
    JsonServiceCls *JsonServicePostData;
    OverlayViewController *ovController;
    NSArray *IndexTitles;
    NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
    NSMutableArray *citylistOfItems;
    NSMutableArray *copyListOfItems;
    NSMutableArray *EmployeeArr;
    BOOL searching;
    BOOL letUserSelectRow;

}


@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *EmployeeArr;
@end



EmployeesVC.m


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.EmployeeArr count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"tableCell";

    CustomMaster *cell = (CustomMaster *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomMaster" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (CustomMaster *) currentObject;

            }
        }

    }

    **NSDictionary *thisRow = [self. EmployeeArr objectAtIndex:row];
    (Getting issue here, the issue is "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS")**




    cell.label1.text = [thisRow objectForKey:@"Name"];
    if(_WSConstEmployeeID !=nil && ![_WSConstEmployeeID isEqual:@"0"] && ![_WSConstEmployeeID isEqual:@""] &&_WSConstEmployeeSelectedIndex ==row  )
    {
        cell .accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell .accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }


    NSString *str=[thisRow objectForKey:@"Id"];
    NSString *stra=_WSConstEmployeeID;
    if ([str isEqualToString:stra]) {
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.highlighted=YES;
    }else
    {
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Where are you initialising CountriesArr?

Comment: I would seem that you are accessing item at index that is out of bounds for the array. Check if `row < CountriesArr.count]`

Comment: where declared and initializing your CountriesArr ?

Comment: `EmployeeArr` count can be more than `CountriesArr` count. You should not fetch the country object by index which is based on the `EmployeeArr` count.

Comment: it is EmployeeArr not CountriesArr. I have updated the code. please go through it

Comment: Out of bounds does not cause a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  It can't be an indexing issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's some weird code for this day and age.

(1) Declaring iVars in the @interface went out of style 7 years ago.  If there are ivars, they are in the .m, usually in a class extension.  Even then, most people don't declare ivars at all, preferring `@property`.

(2) iVars should never start with a capital letter.

(3) That the one property you do have is declared `retain` is also the old way;  typically, that was used pre-ARC or outside of ARC.  Do you have ARC turned on?

If you don't have ARC turned on, then are you retaining `EmployeesArr`?  If not, that is your crash.   If you don't have ARC turned on, why not?  You probably should.